# Take detail from the cell according to date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have created an iOS program for showing "Tip of the day". The program have 2 tabs:

1. Home
2. UITableView (with days)

You write your tips on the *UITableView* by clicking the cell you want to write a tip in. On the correct day I want to show the tip in the *Home* tab. How do I do that?

For example: If the tip for November 1 is "Happy", when itis Novermber 1 I want to show "Happy" on the *Home* tab.

Comment: Are you using UITabbarController?

Comment: Yes and I want the detail from correct cell (according to date) to home tab

Comment: Are you using NSArray to keep those data for dates?

Comment: Yes. recommended for me use NSDictionary for take the deatil to home tab

Comment: Do you have the 1) date information, 2) detail information in that NSDictionary?

Comment: NO. Have me NSArray and UITableView with the Dates: 1 January , 2 January etc and when you select cell you conveyer to detailviewcontroller (the tip)

Comment: I added an answer for this question, please check, if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a method like below in Home page.

```
-(void)updateHomePageWithData:(NSDictionary *)selectedCellData {
    self.labelDetails.text = [selectedCellData valueForKey:@"Message"];
}
```

In UITableView page, call the method in cellForRowAtIndexpath as follows.

```
[self.delegate performSelector:@selector(updateHomePageWithData:) withObject:[arrayOfDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: The name of the homepage its FirstViewController I need to switch the name?

Comment: You dont understand me. I crated app with 2 tabs 1.Home 2.Tips. on tips tab have UITableView with date 1 January , 2 January etc.when you select cell you conveyer to DetailViewController the DetailViewController contains the tip. I want the tip come to Home tab (according to date). you understand?

Comment: I understand. self.delegate is meant for reference variable for the HOMEVIEWCONTROLLER.

Comment: I have a worng at [arrayOfDates it's not found this